# Where i get Performance Tool 'Leak' in XCode 4.2?

Tags: objective-c

Now i switched ios developing from XCode 3.2.5 to XCode 4.2. In XCode 3.2.5 i found the Memory Leak by using the 'Leak' (Performance Tool) from Run -> Run with Performance Tool -> Leak. But, in XCode 4.2 i cant find the Performance Tool 'Leak'. How can i find the Memory leak from XCode 4.2? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Product -> Profile. That will bring up the instrumentation tool in a separate window.

Comment: Thank you Mr.PeterPeiGuo. I found the Profile from Product->Profile. Please update your answer. I got the Leaks tool. Thanks a lot.